# How to pass dynamic values in exception through properties file

Tags: java, regex, exception

How to pass dynamic values in exception from the properties file

1. Resource class

```java
if ((Double.parseDouble(orderRequest.getTriggerPrice()) < sLowerLimit)
                        || (Double.parseDouble(orderRequest.getTriggerPrice()) > sHigherLimit)) {

                    throw new SampleException(SampleConstants.CO_TRIGGER_PRICE_RANGE_ERROR);
                }
```

2. SampleConstant class

```java
public static final String CO_TRIGGER_PRICE_RANGE_ERROR = "EPO0009";
```

3. properties file

```
EPO0009=Price value not within Trigger price range
```

4. exception mapper class

   ```
    if (errorCode.length() < 8) {
        errorMsg = env.getProperty(errorCode);

    } else {
        errorMsg = simpleException.getMessage();
        log.debug("error code is not passed. errorcode: " + errorCode + "errorMsg" + errorMsg);
        errorMsg =env.getProperty(DEFAULT_ERR_MSG);
    }

    log.debug("retrived from properties" + errorMsg);
   ```

//      simpleExceptionResponse.setMessage(StringUtils.isEmpty(simpleException.getMessage())?"":simpleException.getMessage());
simpleExceptionResponse.setStatus(SimpleConstants.FAILURE);
simpleExceptionResponse.setErrorCode(errorCode);
simpleExceptionResponse.setStatusMessage(StringUtils.isEmpty(errorMsg) ? "" : errorMsg);
simpleExceptionResponse.setMsgId(simpleException.getMsgId());
simpleExceptionResponse.setUserId(simpleException.getUserId());
simpleExceptionResponse.setRequestTime(simpleException.getRequestTime());
log.error("simpleException ::" + simpleException);
log.debug("simpleException.getMsgId() ::" + simpleException.getMsgId());
log.debug("simpleException.getUserId() ::" + simpleException.getUserId());
return simpleExceptionResponse;
}

In the above code we just throwing static msg from the properties mapped by sampleConstant class key, but now I need to pass as dynamic value fetched from the properties file and I need to know how to pass dynamic value to the properties file.

I have tried with instant solution but it is not good solution i need any other solution

String dynamicException = "Price value not within Trigger price range, Trigger Price Range is ["+sLowerLimit + "-" +sHigherLimit+ "]";

```
            if ((Double.parseDouble(orderRequest.getTriggerPrice()) < sLowerLimit)
                    || (Double.parseDouble(orderRequest.getTriggerPrice()) > sHigherLimit)) {

                throw new SimpleException(dynamicException);
            }
```

I am expecting a solution as how to do using regex

For example it need to be

> "Price value not within Trigger price range, Trigger Price Range is ["+sLowerLimit + "-" +sHigherLimit+ "]"

instead of

> "Price value not within Trigger price range"

Comment: What is the problem? To me it looks like you have all the variables and just need to build a string with them.

Comment: Where i need to build a string? to get dynamic msg

Comment: Just before you throw the exception

Comment: I have done this way. but it is not the good solution. i am expecting using regex

Comment: How can we know, you haven’t sad a word about this in your question. Please improve the question so it is clear what you are having an issue with and add an attempt at how you tried to solve this.

Comment: Where is the logic to read the property EPO0009? Probably you need to change that part

Comment: Done editing clearly

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholders in the property file:

```
EPO0009=Price value not within Trigger price range, Trigger Price Range is [sLowerLimit-sHigherLimit]
```

And then replace it before throwing the exception:

```
String lowerLimit = getLowerLimit(); // this returns 2
String higherLimit = getHigherLimit(); // this returns 3
String message = errorMsg.replace("sLowerLimit", lowerLimit)
                       .replace("sHigherLimit", higherLimit);
```

So **message** will be:

```
Price value not within Trigger price range, Trigger Price Range is [2-3]
```

Comment: sLowerLimit  and sHigherLimit is a dynamic value not a static value

Comment: The numbers 2 and 3 are just examples, you can add any number you want at runtime. Or what you mean by dynamic?

Comment: ok got it. that errorMsg.replace code in mapper class i need to do?

Comment: Yes in the mapper class, after loading the property EPO0009 into the string errorMsg. I'll update my answer for clarity ;)

Comment: it is a mapper class in that we cannot get lowerlimit and higherlimit value?

Comment: If the higher and lower limit come from the request, then you can pass these values to the mapper class which will replace them in the error message.

Comment: No from the request we didn't get. using query we are getting in resource class. when i pass this value to mapper class like this  SimpleExceptionMapper simpleExceptionMapper = new SimpleExceptionMapper();
    samcoExceptionMapper.setLimitValue(sLowerLimit, sHigherLimit);  it getting null in mapper class when i using that variable